# Construct a linear order on $Y\cup \{x\}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

Let $(Y , \le)$ be a linear order and $x \notin Y$, construct a linear order on $Y\cup \{x\}$.
Well I actually don't understand what construct means and how to do it.
Maybe anyone has an idea?

Comment: Essentially the same as the last one... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4633746/define-a-well-order-on-a-cup-b

Comment: Construct means to invent one. You should write out clearly the axioms/requirements for a linear order, for you'll need to satisfy those. But you are already given a linear order, so it makes sense to extend the one you already have.

Comment: Write the math expressions together: `$(Y, \le)$` instead of `($Y$, $\le$)` and `$Y\cup\{x\}$` instead of `$Y$ $\cup\{x\}$`

Comment: @311411 so, is it just to say that for all a and b from Y and {x} (a<=b or b<=a) ?

Comment: Pick up two  elements $y_0<y_1$ in $Y$ and define $x\le y_1.$. Then the order combined from $(Y,\le)$ and the additional inequality is not linear.